# Using php to write to a log file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

First of I am very very very very bad with php so sorry for this question
I have an application in which i would like to log some debug data
and through my project i make a webrequest to my site storing the information in 
$msg i then want to write the data to my logfile.log on the site.
i first used fopen fwrite fclose, but heard that file_put_contents would be better
especially as i very likely will have several users trying to write to the file at once.
Here's the code:

```
$msg = $_GET['w'];
$logfile= 'logfile.log';
echo file_put_contents($logfile,$msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

But as you might guess the code does nothing for me
i got it working with fopen fwrite fclose
but i wanted to add each user to a new line.

If any smart brain out there would help me I would appreciate it a ton.

Regards.

EDIT:
@Jay
This is how i tried applying it (opening php on the first line)
EDIT: removed 'tag' from code due to a copy/paste error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)
$msg = $_GET['w'];
$logfile= 'logfile.log';
echo file_put_contents($logfile,$msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` There is not enough information in your post to guess what might be happening. Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't see what this has to do with writing a log file.

Comment: There seems to be an error somewhere("the code does nothing for me") @HoboSapiens and I was hoping that know the error would help us to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard like this?
http://puu.sh/ewvV5/c0def0894d.png

Comment: Please post the updated code here @StigRexRørkær. The image is not accessible from the network I am on.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok updated OP

Comment: Copy paste errors? There are some strange characters there. When you ran it did you get any errors? Remove 'tag', that is a copy paste problem on my end.

Comment: `$x = file_put_contents(...); var_dump($x);`. if f_p_c() fails, it returns boolean false, which echoes as nothing at all. var_dump will show if it is a false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `error_log()`?  With the `message_type` set to `3` (second parameter) the message will be written the the file specified in the third parameter:

```
$message = $_GET['w'];
$logfile = 'logfile.log';

// Debug: A line for verifying I have the message
echo "Writing message '$message' to logfile<br>";

error_log($message."\n", 3, $logfile);

// Debug: read back the log file to verify thatthe line has been written
readfile($logfile);
```

Note the `newline` appended to the message as `error_log()` doesn't do this for you.

Note also that permissions must be set to allow the web server to write to the target file. This is true whether using `error_log()` or `file_put_contents()`

PHP reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: This will put the message in PHP's log, not the application's own file.

Comment: @Barmar No - second parameter determines message type. If set to 3 message is written to the file specified in third parameter. Read the reference I linked to.

Comment: @StigRexRørkær What's in `$_GET['w']`? I just copied that from your code snippet.

Comment: @HoboSapiens it gets the string im sending in from my application through webrequest, and should write that to the logfile

Comment: @StigRexRørkær I just set this up on my test server and it writes the message I sent to the file I specified. The only change I need to make was to ensure that Apache had write access to the containing folder so that it could create the file and write to it.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I'm embarrassed to admit you were right.
It was a permission issue.. Thanks guys.. Can you edit your answer so you can get "accept answer" ?